# change FTP server's transport protocol (pyftpdlib)

Tags: python, ftp, pyftpdlib, rudp, transport-layer-protocol

I'm trying to implement a **FTP** server in `Python` and have the ability to manipulate the transport protocol that the server is using.

I have tried to implement the **FTP** server using `pyftpdlib` library, and I couldn't find (in the [docs](https://pyftpdlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html)) an easy way to manipulate the transport protocol.

I think that the library`s default transport protocol is **TCP** and I want to use **RUDP** (reliable UDP).

Is there a way to do that? and if not, is there a diffrent similar library that will allow me to manipulate the tranport protocol?